# How to properly annotate an abstract base component with life cycle hooks in Angular

Tags: angular

I have an abstract base component with life cycle hooks:

```
export abstract class BaseComponent implements OnChanges, OnInit {

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    …
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    …
  }
}
```

And a child component:

```
@Component({
  …
})
export class ChildComponent extends BaseComponent {
```

This will result in `Can't resolve all parameters for BaseComponent: (?, ?, ?).`

The parameter indeed has three parameters. All three values are listed in the `providers` section of the module containing the child component. Adding the base component to the module is not possible since it is not compatible with the type required for `declarations`.

If I add `@Injectable()` to the `BaseComponent` tslint will complain that `In the class "BaseComponent" which have the "@Injectable" decorator, the "ngOnChanges()" hook method is not allowed. Please, drop it. (contextual-life-cycle)`. Everything works fine though.

Adding `@Component()` to the `BaseComponent` results in Webstorm complaning about `Component 'BaseComponent' is not included in a module and will not be available inside a template. Consider adding it to a NgModule declaration`. Again, code runs fine.

Since I like to keep my code clear of any warnings: What is the correct way to implement this pattern?

Comment: `Can't resolve all parameters for BaseComponent: (?, ?, ?)` looks like an error related to the constructor. Can you update your question to show the constructors for the classes.

Comment: Updated to included info about the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not annotating the base component at all (neither `@Injectable` nor `@Component`) did the trick for me.